# Does increasing cpu affect load average?

Tags: linux, cpu-usage, load-average

for example I have a 16 core cpu with load average 10. If I upgrade cpu to 32 core and if ( same traffic , same load , same everything ) , should load average drop or will it stay the same ?

Comment: When you do not "normalise" the load (divide the reported load by the number of cores/CPU's) adding additional cores/CPU's will usually neither increase nor reduce the load. It will most likely also not improve the performance of your applications, as  a load of `10` with 16 cores means that your system utilisation is currently still well within limits.

Answer (score 3):

When you add more cores in theory it should stay the same , as load is from wiki:

```
Interpretation

For single-CPU systems that are CPU bound,
 one can think of load average as a measure of system utilization
 during the respective time period. For systems with multiple CPUs,
 one must divide the load by the number of processors in order to 
 get a comparable measure.
```

So in my opinion load should not decrease